# Navigation bar button item missing after segue style "Replace"

Tags: ios6, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue, uinavigationitem

The iPad app that I'm working on makes use of Storyboards and segues. I'm trying to display a different view controller when the user clicks on different cells in the master view. 
After referring to different tutorials, the steps that were taken were -

- In the `Storyboard`, `Master View Controller`, created static cells for the table view and added 3 different rows (i.e. cell 1, cell 2, cell 3)
- Added a `View Controller`, selected it and attached a `Navigation Controller` to it (`Editor` -> `Embed In` -> `Navigation Controller`)
- From cell 1 in `Master View`, I did a ctrl-click on the `Navigation Controller`.
- Chose `Segue Style` "Replace" and `Destination` "Detail Split"
- In tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath, added [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NewViewController" sender:self] to do the transition.

The result that I see is the detail view gets replaced.

But the navigation bar does not have the bar button item `Master`.

So I'm unable to click the `Master` button which would show the table containing cells from where I can navigate to a different view.

I've already read many blogs and seen commentary which talk about replacing a segue for similar problems. However nobody seems to have faced this specific issue while using storyboards and segues.

From my understanding using segues should help me achieve what I want. From those who have tried this approach, any pointers in the right direction will be helpful.

Comment: *[What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?*

Comment: @Jules This was my first question on SO. The questions i ask in future will be more clear i hope :)

Comment: The link below has the problem nicely described and I was able to fully understand why the navigation bar item was missing while using storyboards.. Check out the answer by oneMhz <http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1546>

Comment: Thats a very interesting link that you showed. I'll put it use soon. Thanks.

Comment: Not that it matters much at this remove, @JulesMazur, but how on earth would JSFiddle help anyone demonstrate their iOS code?

Comment: @Vinny, if you have a solution please answer the question and select your own answer.

Comment: @ggrana i dont think ill be able to provide a working sample at the moment because of time constraints. However, ill try to put my understanding into a solution soon. There's a sample project in the link that I sent. Did that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the `Segue Style` from `Replace` to `Push`. It should resolve your problem.

When you push a `UIViewController` on a `UINavigationController`, it will be added to a stack and you will be able to navigate back :

**Your navigation controller stack before tapping "Detail":**

```
Master
```

**Your navigation controller after tapping detail and navigating a little more ...:**

```
Master -> Detail (Navigation button is displayed) -> Some other details (Navigation button is displayed) -> And maybe some more (Navigation button is displayed)
```

When you call a new segue using `Replace` like you did, the `Master` will be replaced with `Detail`, and you will not be able to navigate back because Master was replaced and it's not on the stack anymore.

**Your navigation controller stack before tapping "Detail":**

```
Master
```

**Your navigation controller after tapping detail using replace like you did:**

```
Detail (no navigation button because master was replaced and we don't have nothing more on the stack)
```